# Duplicate question modified stay as duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I ask a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25763954/3442166) but it was marked as duplicate.

I edit my question to explain why my problem was different but the question stay as duplicate. I finally have an answer from MSDN and I want to share it on Stack Overflow but I can't answer.

So what I have to do in this case?

Comment: I cannot judge the merits because I don't use that tech. a) Maybe the community disagrees with you. b) Maybe you could post your answer on the other question?

Comment: i can not judge the merits either (i am not a C# guy) but its just one user with gold badge who closed it so possibilities are there

Comment: @Louis Yes it's that I do, I answer on the "duplicate" but it was just for answering on my own question that was (I agree, just a little bit) different

Comment: Incorrect duplicats do happen from time to time. When there are similar questions you could perhaps emphasize that it's not a duplicate at the start of the question.

Comment: @simonzack Yes you're right, I will do this. Thank's

Comment: Another option would be to ask in a chatroom for people to reopen if they believe it is not a dupe with the edit. Like, the [C# room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c). But realize that they are not obligated to reopen or even to look at it.

Comment: Meta effect accomplished.

Comment: @codeMagic: Yeah, but that one pompous moron felt obliged to close as "duplicate" without even understanding what the question is about. Some rules are dumb. Why is it so difficult to revert actions of one douche?

Comment: @simonzack At this point I am feeling it isn't "from time to time", it is "far too often".